# How to read N records from a file using Python script where N is the user input in a PHP page?

Tags: php, python

This is the PHP-code which takes user input for the number of songs to be       retrieved.

```
  <?php
   if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
   {

    $val = htmlentities($_GET['val']);
    $tmp = shell_exec("python /opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/IR/song.py .$val    ");
    echo $tmp;
   }
  ?>

    <h1 class="register-title">Songs by User-ID</h1>
    <form class="register" action = "" method="get">

 <input type="text" class="register-input" id="val" placeholder="No of Songs">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Retrieve" class="Retrieve-button">
   </form>
```

This is the python code which takes the argument from php file and executes the script.
    Python ex.py file

```
import sys
result = sys.argv[1]
N=result
f=open("song.txt")
for i in range(N):
   line=f.next().strip()   
   print line
f.close()
```

Comment: The problem i am facing is that the variable N in the python script is not being used to print the lines from the text file. what could be the reason ? could somebody pls help me.

Comment: `sys.argv` is a bunch of strings. But `range()` takes an integer. Try `result = int(sys.argv[1])`

Comment: Undefined index: val in /opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/userid.php on line 5

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dashboard/ex.py", line 2, in result = int(sys.argv[1]) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'

Comment: Yeah, I see you have a dot just before `$val` in your python call. Not sure why, but you can delete it.

Comment: Yes that worked.. thanks:)